# Entity Date Modelset Generates Errors in Visual Web Developer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, frameworks, entity

I attempted to add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my Visual Web Developer 2010 Express project and it generates but returns a whole slew of errors. Why is this generating errors? Here are the main errors:
'Public Property ID As Integer' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. 
Method 'Onaddress_IDChanging' cannot be declared 'Partial' because only one method 'Onaddress_IDChanging' can be marked 'Partial'.
'_line1' is already declared as 'Private _line1 As String' in this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a bug in Microsoft Visual Studio. Apparently certain keywords are reserved and when used in a table name/property results in numerous errors.